# Keydown effect, alert if keyup before effect finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, keydown, keyup

My goal: Press and HOLD space key while an effect occurs (to simulate a fingerprint scan). If user releases key before effect finishes, I want to display a confirm message. The keydown part works fine and proceeds to function "process", but no error message is displayed on keyup if it is released before the effect finishes. This is what I have...

```
var active = false;

$(document).one("keydown", function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode == 32) && (active == false)) {
      active = true;
      $(".panel_1").slideDown(5000, function() {
        active = false;
        $(".panel_1").slideUp(2000, function() {process(); })
      }); 
    }
});

$(document).one("keyup",function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode == 32) && (active == true)) {
      var r=confirm("Oops! You must HOLD down the space key until scan is complete. Press OK to try again, or Cancel to return to homepage.");
      if (r==true) {
        reset();
      }
      else {
        window.location.replace("home.html");
      } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are releasing the key during the first slideDown animation.  According to your code, once it starts to slide up your active gets set to false and then makes it so the keyup event will not trigger.

Also as a side note I'd recommend using triple = in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/D52eq/ but note that the confirmation message occurs only if the space bar is released during the `.slideDown()` phase of the effect - you're setting `active = false;` *before* the `.slideUp()` call.

If you want the confirmation if the space bar is released before completion of the entire animation and `process()` call then try this:

```
$(document).one("keydown", function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode == 32) && (!active)) {
      active = true;
      $(".panel_1").slideDown(5000).slideUp(2000, function() {
         process();
         active = false;
      })
    }
});
```

Note that then you can just chain the `.slideDown()` and `.slideUp()`, you don't need to supply a callback function to `.slideDown()`. Also I've replaced `active == false` with `!active`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D52eq/1/

Comment: I switched the active == false to !active and chained the .slideDown() and .slideUp() to eliminate the callback function. Now it works!  I originally placed the active = false after the .slideUp(), but nothing happened.  When I put it between .slideDown() and .slideUp(), the keyDown worked again, so I figured that was better than non-functional code! Thanks for your help! ;)